# Mismatch between fitting curve and origin data

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, smoothing, mismatch

I want to plot my data but there are edges in the curve so I am trying to smooth it using
polynomial (tried different degrees), spline, or exponential functions but there is a mismatch with the original data.

Here are the codes and plots:

## Data

```
copper = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 15])

transmission = np.array([1.000, 0.269, 0.150, 0.097, 0.064, 0.046, 0.026, 0.020, 0.012, 0.003])
```

[mismatching plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCVFz.png)
[mismatch -exponential function code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMxmY.png)

## Data

```
copper = np.array([0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 15])
transmission = np.array([1.000, 0.169, 0.077, 0.043, 0.025, 0.016, 0.011, 0.005, 0.003, 0.000])
```

[the curve is uneven](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urScQ.png)
[uneven-spline function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH5fo.png)

Comment: Why is only a small part of your code included as text?

Comment: I suppose your data is best modeled by an exponential curve, not by a polynomial or splines.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Do you know how we can get rid of the mismatching with the exponential? I tried to adjust the initial guesses and increase the generated numbers but no improvement :(

Comment: Picture are very poor medium to exchange textual data. Never take screenshot of code, data, error. Copy paste and format it instead.

Comment: An exponential decay fits well if you ignore the first value, if the data is not correct you can't do wonders. In any case, this doesn't really look like a programming question.

Comment: @Bashaer, If you try a slightly different curve fit: y = A.exp( -B.x^n ) then you can fit your data. In the first case, A, B, n = 1.000, 1.313, 0.5282. In the second case, A, B, n = 1.000, 1.780, 0.5197